# i want to convert 4/1/2019 to 1/4/2019 in my dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i want to swap month and date in a date in a column of a dataframe

i have tried all the below methods:

```
#df_combined1['BILLING_START_DATE_x'] = pd.to_datetime(df_combined1['BILLING_START_DATE_x'], format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
#df_combined1['BILLING_START_DATE_x'] = df_combined1['BILLING_START_DATE_x'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%d-%m-%Y'))
#df_combined1['BILLING_START_DATE_x'] = pd.to_datetime(df_combined1['BILLING_START_DATE_x'], format='%m-%d-%Y')
```

i need to swap month and the day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If format all datetimes is `DD/MM/YYYY`:

```
df_combined1['BILLING_START_DATE_x'] = (pd.to_datetime(df_combined1['BILLING_START_DATE_x'], 
                                         format='%d/%m/%Y')
                                          .dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

---

If format all datetimes is `MM/DD/YYYY`:

```
df_combined1['BILLING_START_DATE_x'] = (pd.to_datetime(df_combined1['BILLING_START_DATE_x'], 
                                         format='%m/%d/%Y')
                                          .dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Comment: @JagruthiC please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer if it helped you. Thanks :)